# CSS: Setting rgba's alpha without overriding current BGcolor

Tags: css, cross-browser

Is it possible to change an element's background RGBA's alpha without actually changing the color?

Or setting the color without overriding the alpha?

Prefferably cross-browser and without Javascript.

I can do it obviously by specifying the rgba color but I'd like to do classes for each %10 of transparency, and be able to set any color.

Thanks :)

Comment: You could use `opacity:x;` (where x is a number 0 <= x <= 1) but it will affect the entire element (and children), not just the background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS stylesheet:

```
.trans10 {
   background-color: 33ccaa;
   opacity:0.1;
   filter:alpha(opacity=10); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

.trans20 {
   background-color: 33ccaa;
   opacity:0.2;
   filter:alpha(opacity=20); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

And so on...

Comment: I was hoping to do it without opacity or filter, as I'd only like to affect the background. Nesting isn't an option either. Is it impossible to do what I'm wanting?

Comment: Then you should change only the background color, there are some color calcs online to keep hue and saturation changeing brightness.